# Is there a way to use model's name as a reference for a plugin's topic? (Citadel or Fortress)

Tags: ignition-fortress, sdformat, gazebo-ignition, ignition-citadel

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For example,  the current section:

```
     <sensor name='gpu_lidar' type='gpu_lidar'>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <topic>ultrasonic0</topic>
      <update_rate>20</update_rate>
```

This doesn't have to be gpu_lidar only. It can be joint_controller, battery or any plugin type.

So, the topic will be displaying as `/ultrasonic0`, right?

So, is there a way to do like this:
`/<model_name_from_file>/ultrasonic0`?

I wanted to duplicate robots in future along with rename set as true in the same world so I was hoping like

/robot_00/ultrasonic0
/robot_01/ultrasonic0
/robot_02/ultrasonic0

And so on.

Is this possible? I tried `<namespace>` and `<topic></topic>` but it end up an absolute path which I don't want that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27847/is-there-a-way-to-use-model%27s-name-as-a-reference-for-a-plugin%27s-topic?-(citadel-or-fortress)/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2022-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is currently not supported. Your best bet is to remove `<topic>` and use the topic generated by default. Feel free to open an issue requesting the feature,  or better yet, a PR with an implementation :).

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2022-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2022-02-21**:
Okay, thank you so much for your time! Do you have any clue for me to start somewhere so I can PR if it's acceptable to Gazebo team?